# Issues with comparason of UTC dates

Tags: php

I'm having a problem comparing two dates and cannot figure out what is going wrong. I am parsing an XML file and want to include an item if it is within the current date.

The dates are the same but it is not being included. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or maybe not understanding?

```
date_default_timezone_set( "UTC" );

$unix = date( 'U', strtotime( $item['pubDate'] ) ); // $item['pubDate'] = 'Sunday, June 08, 2014 12:59:36 AM'

if(date('Y-m-d', $unix) == date("Y-m-d")){ // My date = 1402209579 - me  = 06 / 08 / 14 @ 6:39:39am UTC
  ... Expecting this item to be included as the dates are the same
}
```

Comment: its the same here http://codepad.viper-7.com/EOflho just used your codes

Comment: Thanks Jake. Maybe you can explain why some items are included in my `if` block and others are not. Maybe I am not understanding something about the time diff between the 2?

Comment: I have put the actual string in the comment to the right of my if block. That is exactly what the date coming from the XML looks like

Comment: OK. If I view the source, I can see that the date is what I have there in the comment. This is one example where the item should have been included but wasn't. It's weird.

Comment: @kevinabelita, Thanks. I see that they are the same. Why isn't it being included on my local machine? Does my timezone have anything to do with this? I wouldn't think so... The times are in UTF

Comment: @NaN i wouldn't think about the timezone since its already set to utc, i dont know maybe on the xml files? im just shooting in the dark here, but can you try `trim($item['pubDate'])`

Comment: Sure. I'll trim it and let you know. brb

Comment: @kevinabelita, Kev, I think you're onto something here. After trimming the date, it's now being included. I would have never guessed that.

Comment: @NaN check out Jake's answer, that should fix it, if it did malformed that data inside the xml

Comment: @kevinabelita, Thanks Kev. It does seem to work. Thanks for putting me on the right track there. Who would have thought...?

Comment: @NaN no problem, i dont know, probably just an idea, just shootin' in the dark, who would have thought, it got hit haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd to me because using your sample code with the sample date of `Sunday, June 08, 2014 12:59:36 AM` works fine for me. But since you say some dates work in the XML file & others don’t, I think there might be some character oddities in the dates in there.  So will suggest using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)—coupled with [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)—to clean your date data before acting on it:

```
date_default_timezone_set( "UTC" );

$pubDate = 'Sunday, June 08, 2014 12:59:36 AM'; // $item['pubDate'] = 'Sunday, June 08, 2014 12:59:36 AM'

$pubDate_cleaned = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9,: ]/is', '', $pubDate));

$unix = date('U',strtotime($pubDate_cleaned));

if (date('Y-m-d', $unix) == date("Y-m-d")) { // My date = 1402209579 - me  = 06 / 08 / 14 @ 6:39:39am UTC
  echo 'Yes! The dates match!';
}
```

The idea of the regex `/[^a-zA-Z0-9,: ]/is` is to remove any characters in the string that are not letters, not numbers & not the characters `,`, `:` or a space within the date formatting. Then the `trim` cleans the space on the left & right of the string so it’s all clean.

This should truly normalize the dates if there are any unicode gremlins or other things you might not want in there for the `strtotime` conversion.

Comment: Jake, thanks. kevinabelita suggested `trim`ming the date and that did it. I also see you are trimming in your example as well as using regex to normalize the data. I like that.

Comment: Hey Jake, I just noticed something else. Here is another pubDate from another XML file. This one uses GMT. `Sun, 08 Jun 2014 04:59:36 GMT`. `strtotime` shouldn't have a problem with that, right?

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks a bunch for seeing me through this. It's late and I'm not thinking clearly. :)

Comment: Thanks bro, that helps me. I'll actually make a note of it. :)